# Find "Sign in" button with webdriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

The website code is:

```
<div class="dc-button-wrapper">
   <button class="dc-button nostyle dc-background-primary" data-component="Button" type="submit" name=""> 
     <span class="dc-button-text">Sign in 
</span></button></div>
```

I'm trying to press the "Sign in" button with the following piece of code but it doesn't work.

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="dc-button-wrapper"]').click()
```

What needs to be changed? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Class can be duplicate many times in html body. So only using class is not enough for driver to identify the locator. You should be more specific with your xpath.

Try the following example:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(), "Sign in")]').click()

self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(), "Sign in")]/parent::button').click()

self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="dc-button-wrapper"]/button/span[contains(text(), "Sign in")]').click()
```

### Reference

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp

https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html